# How to fetch all unread mail with attachment as an array ? i am using following code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use this code, but I don't understand how we fetch the attachment with the sender's email . This is my code, and I tried so many times with different-2 code but yet I get no solutions.

```
public function myresume(&$response)
{

  $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
  $username = 'My gmail username';
  $password = 'password';
  $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

  $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

  if($emails)
   {
    $output = '';
    rsort($emails);
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
 }
 echo $output ; 


} 
imap_close($inbox);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to get unseen email and store in any folder

```
        $server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
        $login = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
        /* try to connect */
        $connection = imap_open($server,$login,$password) or die('Cannot connect to your sever: ' . imap_last_error());

        /*get only  unseen mail from inbox*/

        $result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN');

        $max_emails = 1;

        /* if any emails found, iterate through each email */
        if($emails) {

            $count = 1;
            /* put the newest emails on top */
            rsort($emails);
            $attachments = array();

            /* for every email... */
            foreach($emails as $email_number)
            {
                /* get mail structure */
                $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

                if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts))
                {
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++)
                    {
                        $attachments[$i] = array(
                            'is_attachment' => false,
                            'filename' => '',
                            'name' => '',
                            'attachment' => ''
                        );

                        if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters)
                        {
                            foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object)
                            {
                                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename')
                                {
                                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                    $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters)
                        {
                            foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object)
                            {
                                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name')
                                {
                                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                    $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment'])
                        {

                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                            /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                            if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3)
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                            }
                            /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                            elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4)
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            imap_close($inbox);

            /*store mail attachments to locally*/
            foreach($attachments as $attachment)
            {

                if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
                {

                    $filename = $attachment['name'];
                    if(empty($filename))
                        $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                    if(empty($filename))
                        $filename = time() . ".dat";

                    $fp = fopen($path." ".$email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                    $csvFileName=$path." ".$email_number . "-" . $filename;
                    fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);

                    fclose($fp);

                    $array=$fields=array();
                    $i=0;

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use imap_fetchstructure to understand the mail structure and fetch the attachments. Below is a example copied from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php
(code to parse and decode all types of messages, including attachments.)

```
 <?php  
  function getmsg ($mbox, $mid)
  {
     // input $mbox = IMAP stream, $mid = message id
     // output all the following:
     global $charset, $htmlmsg, $plainmsg, $attachments;
     $htmlmsg = $plainmsg = $charset = '';
     $attachments = array();

     // HEADER
     $h = imap_header($mbox, $mid);
     // add code here to get date, from, to, cc, subject...

     // BODY
     $s = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $mid);
     if (! $s->parts) // simple
        getpart($mbox, $mid, $s, 0); // pass 0 as part-number
     else { // multipart: cycle through each part
        foreach ($s->parts as $partno0 => $p)
           getpart($mbox, $mid, $p, $partno0 + 1);
     }
  }

  function getpart ($mbox, $mid, $p, $partno)
  {
     // $partno = '1', '2', '2.1', '2.1.3', etc for multipart, 0 if simple
     global $htmlmsg, $plainmsg, $charset, $attachments;

     // DECODE DATA
     $data = ($partno) ? imap_fetchbody($mbox, $mid, $partno) :    // multipart
     imap_body($mbox, $mid); // simple
                            // Any part may be encoded, even plain text messages,
                            // so check everything.
     if ($p->encoding == 4)
        $data = quoted_printable_decode($data);
     elseif ($p->encoding == 3)
        $data = base64_decode($data);

        // PARAMETERS
        // get all parameters, like charset, filenames of attachments, etc.
     $params = array();
     if ($p->parameters)
        foreach ($p->parameters as $x)
           $params[strtolower($x->attribute)] = $x->value;
     if ($p->dparameters)
        foreach ($p->dparameters as $x)
           $params[strtolower($x->attribute)] = $x->value;

        // ATTACHMENT
        // Any part with a filename is an attachment,
        // so an attached text file (type 0) is not mistaken as the message.
     if ($params['filename'] || $params['name']) {
        // filename may be given as 'Filename' or 'Name' or both
        $filename = ($params['filename']) ? $params['filename'] : $params['name'];
        // filename may be encoded, so see imap_mime_header_decode()
        $attachments[$filename] = $data; // this is a problem if two files have
                                         // same name
     }

     // TEXT
     if ($p->type == 0 && $data) {
        // Messages may be split in different parts because of inline attachments,
        // so append parts together with blank row.
        if (strtolower($p->subtype) == 'plain')
           $plainmsg.
        trim($data) . "\n\n";
          else
              $htmlmsg. = 
        $data . "<br><br>";
        $charset = $params['charset']; // assume all parts are same charset
     }   

     // EMBEDDED MESSAGE
     // Many bounce notifications embed the original message as type 2,
     // but AOL uses type 1 (multipart), which is not handled here.
     // There are no PHP functions to parse embedded messages,
     // so this just appends the raw source to the main message.
     elseif ($p->type == 2 && $data) {
          $plainmsg. = 
        $data . "\n\n";
     }

     // SUBPART RECURSION
     if ($p->parts) {
        foreach ($p->parts as $partno0 => $p2)
           getpart($mbox, $mid, $p2, $partno . '.' . ($partno0 + 1)); // 1.2, 1.2.1, etc.
     }
  }
 ?>
```